# Dynamic web form not loading fully on using Python Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to fill a web form using Python Selenium webdriver.
When filled manually - Upon selecting the first dropdown option, it adds more fields to the form.

However, when I am trying to select value in first dropdown using code, it does not add new fields.

Can someone let me know what I am missing here.

Form site: https://www.cersai.org.in/CERSAI/dbtrsrch.prg

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://www.cersai.org.in/CERSAI/dbtrsrch.prg")

driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('borrowerType').selectedIndex = '1'")
driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('assetCategory').selectedIndex = '1'")
```

Comment: CERSAI
Central Registry of Securitisation Asset Reconstruction and Security Interest of India
The CERSAI site is under maintenance.

The site will not be available from 23-Aug-2021 09:00 PM till 24-Aug-2021 12:00 AM .

Comment: I am getting this as of now.

Comment: Yeah, looks like the site is under maintenance. I will keep a check and update here once it is up

Comment: Sure, also please use @ to reply

Comment: sure, @cruisepandey

Comment: @cruisepandey - just a heads up - site is up now. if you don't mind, would you please take a look at it

Comment: that's an issue with Application, we really can not do anything about that from automation perspective.

Comment: also, in automation window if you try to select the second drop down you will see the first drop down selected value is getting left out meaning unselected

Comment: oh, okay. thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @cruisepandey - finally managed to load the dynamic fields which appear upon choosing value of first dropdown. 
This worked -

`driver.find_element_by_xpath(r"//[@id='borrowerType']").send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)`

Comment: thnx for sharing. but still it is strange, I got to learn something today. :) cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Sending arrow down key works.
`driver.find_element_by_xpath(r"//[@id='borrowerType']").send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)`